# How to solve this: two functions x = sin(x)/a

Tags: c, math, binary-search

I tried to solve this equation in different ways but no luck:

Find the number of points of two functions.

```
f(x) = sin(x)  
y = a
```

at a given a. In this case lets say `a = 0.15`

```
sin(x) = ax
= 0.15x
x = sin(x)/0.15
```

???

Can any one help with this question?

this is the question in the exact words:

Write a C program that would read in the value a and write out all the solutions (i.e. roots) of the equation `sin(x) = a*x`

NOTE: This equation has for sure one solution: `x = 0`. However, for low values of `a`, the line representing the equation `y = a*x` is sufficiently close to horizontal line to cross the sine wave several times. Your program should calculate and print the number of roots and their values.

HINT: Suppose you are to solve an equation `f(x) = 0`, where `f(x)` is a continuous function. Suppose further that you can find two values `xlow` and `xhigh` such that `f(xlow) < 0` and `f(xhigh) > 0` and the function `f(x)` crosses the x-axis only once somewhere between these values. You could proceed using the so called "binary search" technique, as follows:

> 1. Estimate the solution x as x = (xlow + xhigh) / 2.0
> 2. If |f(x)| < epsilon then print x as solution and exit; else
> 3. If f(x) < 0 then substitute xlow = x else substitute xhigh = x
> 4. Go to (1)

Use epsilon = 0.001

Comment: You said $a=.15$, but then you replaced $a$ in your equation with $.15x$. Is that a mistake?

Comment: @GTonyJacobs I think the orginal equation should have been $\sin(x)=ax$ instead.

Comment: "Find the number of points of two functions." and what follows does not make sense. Pls check it.

Comment: @leonbloy i think he means "points of intersection of 0.15x and sin(x)"

Comment: @Sabyasachi But then the second line should be $g(x)=a x$, no?

Comment: Further : why use $f(x)$ for the first function and $y$ for the second? And "at a given $a$" should rather be  "for a given $a$"?

Comment: The edit "this is the question in the exact words..." reveals that this is a programming problem. It belongs on stackoverflow in my opinion.

Comment: You want to find the `x` points where `sin(x)` intersects `a*x`. You can use the function `f(x) = sin(x) - a*x` and find its zeros.

Answer (score 1):

> You could proceed using the so called "binary search" technique

This is the key to the solution. Actually it *is* the solution. Let me draw two functions:

```
           f(x)   g(x)
            /    --
           /   --
          /  --
         / --
        /--
       -*
     --/
   -- /
 --  /

 ^                 ^
 |                 |
 xlow              xhigh
```

You have `xlow` and `xhigh` as an estimate of where `f(x)` crosses `g(x)`. In your question, `f(x) = ax` and `g(x) = sin(x)`.

First, let's see why `xlow` and `xhigh` make a good estimate. If you notice, at `xlow`, we have `f(x) < g(x)` and at `xhigh` we have `f(x) > g(x)`. Since the functions are continuous, then there is some point somewhere in between where `f(x) == g(x)`.

Now let's look at the middle-point between `xlow` and `xhigh`:

```
           f(x)   g(x)
            /    --
           /   --
          /  --
         / --
        /--
       -*
     --/
   -- /
 --  /

 ^        ^        ^
 |        |        |
 xlow     xmid     xhigh
```

Now at `xmid`, we have `f(x) > g(x)` (in this example). So:

```
f(xhigh) > g(xhigh)
f(xmid)  > g(xmid)
f(xlow)  < g(xlow)
```

Since between `xmid` and `xlow`, the functions change bigger-ness-ship (in other words, `f(x) - g(x)` changes its sign), then the answer is for sure between `xlow` and `xmid` (note that there could still be an even number of solutions between `xmid` and `xhigh`, but we can't really tell at this point).

So, if we assign `xhigh = xmid`, we would have:

```
       f(x)  g(x)
         /--
       -*
     --/
   -- /
 --  /

 ^        ^
 |        |
 xlow     xhigh
```

But this is the same problem as before! Except that we shrank the possible location of the solution by half. Repeating we have:

```
       f(x)  g(x)
         /--
       -*
     --/
   -- /
 --  /

 ^    ^    ^
 |    |    |
 xlow xmid xhigh

f(xhigh) < g(xhigh)
f(xmid)  > g(xmid)
f(xlow)  > g(xlow)
```

This time, the sign of `f(x) - g(x)` changes between `xmid` and `xhigh`, so we would do `xlow = xmid` to cut away the first half of the range which we are not interested in. We get:

```
       f(x)  g(x)
         /--
       -*
     --/

      ^    ^
      |    |
      xlow xhigh
```

Again, the same problem, except we shrank the range where the solution could possibly be by half.

Repeating this in a while loop, there would be some point where `|f(xmid) - g(xmid)|` becomes almost zero (say smaller than 0.000001 (or 1e-6) (also note that absolute value)). In that case, we stop searching and we say that that particular `xmid` is the answer. (See [here](http://floating-point-gui.de/) for why we don't check for equality, but closeness).

---

There is still one problem. With your particular functions, there could be many cross-sections. How do we find `xlow` and `xhigh`? Well, we want the range `[xlow, xhigh]` to contain only one solution. So we can incrementally find those ranges and find the cross-section in between them.

Assuming `a > 0` (and solutions for `x > 0`), this is how the graph would look like:

```
                              ----- f(x) = ax
   _           _         __*__         _ g(x) = sin(x)
  / \         /_*___----- / \         /
 /   *____---*-  \       /   \       /
|---- |     |     |     |     |     |
      |     |     |     |     |     |
       \   /       \   /       \   /
        \_/         \_/         \_/
```

So let's see where the solutions can be. For sure, it's not where `sin(x) < 0`. Then on `[2kπ, 2kπ + π/2]` and `[2kπ + π/2, 2kπ + π]` there *could* be one solution each. The initial `[0, π / 2]` may or may not have a solution depending on `a`. So the safest way is to enumerate all such ranges, calculate `f(x) - g(x)` for both `xlow` and `xhigh` and look at their signs. If the sign doesn't change, there is no solution and we can move on. If it does change, we perform the binary search above.

When does the algorithm end? We know that `g(x) = sin(x) <= 1` and we know that for `a > 0`, `f(x) = ax` is always increasing. So when you have `f(xlow) > 1`, then for sure there are no more solutions.

The algorithm would thus be:

```
Main Algorithm:
for k = 0,1,...
    xlow = 2kπ
    xhigh = 2kπ + π/2
    binary_search(xlow, xhigh)

    xlow = 2kπ + π/2
    xhigh = 2kπ + π
    binary_search(xlow, xhigh)

binary_search:
if axlow-sin(xlow) and axhigh-sin(xhigh) have the same sign
    return no result in this range
do
    xmid = (xhigh + xlow) / 2
    diff = axmid - sin(axmid)
    if diff and axlow-sin(xlow) have the same sign
        xlow = xmid
    else
        xhigh = xmid
while abs(diff) > epsilon
return xmid
```

For the cases where `a < 0`, the solution is similar (except the ranges change to the other half of the `sin` cycle). By the way, for each `x` that you find above, `-x` is also a solution!

Comment: You will find that there are more hits if you search for "bisection method". And one should really avoid that, it is a rather slow method, look under "false position method" or "regula falsi" for faster converging methods. -- Also, there are values for a where the line ax is close to being a tangent but still intersects an upwards bow of y=sin(x). Then bisection will report the same sign at the end points of the search interval and miss the solutions inside.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, there can only be solutions for

```
-1 <= ax <= 1
```

The monotonicity of the difference function h(x)=sin(x)-ax is the same on all intervals between the roots of the derivative h'(x)=cos(x)-a, and they are also the local maxima and minima of this function. So use the points

```
arccos(a), 2*pi-arccos(a), 2*pi+arccos(a), 4*pi-arccos(a), 4*pi+arccos(a), ...
```

as long as they are smaller than 1/abs(a) to define the search intervals. Use inside each of them, as per the answer of Shahbaz, the bisection method, or better the Illinois variant of the regula falsi method.

Comment: Should there be a `-arccos(a)` in the list?

Comment: No. The first non-negative solution is x=0. h(0)=0, and h'(x)>0 from 0 to arccos(a), so that h(x)>0 on that segment. To have a root between 0 and pi/2 one needs a=1-eps close to 1. Then arccos(1-eps) is about sqrt(2*eps) and sin(x)=sqrt(2*eps-eps^2)>a*x=sqrt(2*eps-4*eps^2+2*eps^3) at that point, i.e., h(sqrt(2*eps))>0, while the next point x=2*pi-sqrt(2*eps) has the opposite relation, h(x) approx. -2*pi<0.

Comment: `sin(x)` is an odd function, as well as `ax`.  I'd expect if `x` is a solution to the problem, `-x` would also be a solution.  OP does not appear to have a limit to a `non-negative solution` so `-arccos(a), -2*pi-arccos(a), -2*pi+arccos(a), -4*pi-arccos(a), -4*pi+arccos(a), ...` are also solutions.

Comment: Yes of course, I had the impression that that was implicitely understood in all the answers. So let me restate: Aside x=0 there are no additional solutions between -arccos(a) and arccos(a). And you do not need to examine the negative intervals, since with the positive solutions all negative solutions are also known.

Answer (score -1):

A brutefore approach without any optimization (therefore a naive approach) would to run a for loop on x, x running from 0 to 2*PI, PI = 22.0/7.0, and loop increment by say 0.001, if you get abs(sin(x) - a*x) < epsilon, where epsilon say equals to some kow value like 0.001 (depends on your granularity), you get it! This would solve your equation sin(x) = a*x

Comment: -1: There are solutions outside [0, 2*pi]. This was mentioned in the "NOTE" in the question.